# React Native: importing a component within componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to call a function in componentWillMount, but I don't want it to sit in the same file.

Is there a way to reference the function in componentWillMount?

Here is the code, I have left off a lot of the code which isn't relevant to this problem as I'm in the middle of refactoring (thus this question!):

Midpoint.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Midpoint extends Component {

  midpoint(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    const rad = (Math.PI) / 180;
    const rlat1 = lat1 * rad;
    const rlng1 = lng1 * rad;
    const rlat2 = lat2 * rad;
    const rlng2 = lng2 * rad;

    const dlng = rlng2 - rlng1;
    const Bx = Math.cos(rlat2) * Math.cos(dlng);
    const By = Math.cos(rlat2) * Math.sin(dlng);

    const lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(rlat1) + Math.sin(rlat2),
              Math.sqrt(((Math.cos(rlat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(rlat1) + Bx)) + (By * By)));
    const lng3 = rlng1 + Math.atan2(By, (Math.cos(rlat1) + Bx));

    const lat = (lat3 * 180) / Math.PI;
    const lng = (lng3 * 180) / Math.PI;
    this.setState({ lat2: lat, lng2: lng });
  }
}

export default Midpoint;
```

This is the function I want to import into the below:

ResultsPage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import getDirections from 'react-native-google-maps-directions';
import axios from 'axios';
import Midpoint from './Midpoint';
import { Card, CardSection, Button } from './common';

class ResultsPage extends Component {
  state = {}

  componentWillMount() {
.then(response => { Midpoint.midpoint(this.state.p1Latitude, this.state.p1Longitude, this.state.p2Latitude, this.state.p2Longitude) })

}
```

The error I receive is `_Midpoint2.default.midpoint is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a component like it is was a function, if the only objective of Midpoint is to calculate the latlng then don`t make it a React Component just export the function

```
    export default function calculateMidpoint(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    const rad = (Math.PI) / 180;
    const rlat1 = lat1 * rad;
    const rlng1 = lng1 * rad;
    const rlat2 = lat2 * rad;
    const rlng2 = lng2 * rad;

    const dlng = rlng2 - rlng1;
    const Bx = Math.cos(rlat2) * Math.cos(dlng);
    const By = Math.cos(rlat2) * Math.sin(dlng);

    const lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(rlat1) + Math.sin(rlat2),
              Math.sqrt(((Math.cos(rlat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(rlat1) + Bx)) + (By * By)));
    const lng3 = rlng1 + Math.atan2(By, (Math.cos(rlat1) + Bx));

    const lat = (lat3 * 180) / Math.PI;
    const lng = (lng3 * 180) / Math.PI;
     return { lat, lng }
  }
```

but if Midpoint has to be a component just extract the logic like we did in the last example and put it in a diferent file and call it in the Results and Midpoint components

let say you put the function in Utils.js in the same directory

ResultsPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import getDirections from 'react-native-google-maps-directions';
import axios from 'axios';
import calculateMidpoint from './Utils';
import { Card, CardSection, Button } from './common';

class ResultsPage extends Component {
  state = {}

  componentWillMount() {
let latlng = calculateMidpoint(this.state.p1Latitude, this.state.p1Longitude, this.state.p2Latitude, this.state.p2Longitude) 

}
```

and Midpoint.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import calculateMidpoint from './Utils';
class Midpoint extends Component {

  midpoint(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    let latlng = calculateMidpoint(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
    this.setState({ lat2: latlng.lat, lng2: latlng,lng });
  }
}

export default Midpoint;
```

also, you have an error in componentWillMount where you are calling a .then() out of nowhere